# AWS Cognito Not getting Google custom attributes from response

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, aws-userpools

I've set up cognito user pool and attached google as an IDP,

When signing-up through Google, the protected attributes are not mapped at all.

Inside Google the authorize scope:

```
email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read
```

Attribute mapping

[image: Attribute mapping]

Resource server to fetch the data

[image: Resource server to fetch the data]

App client settings

[image: App client settings]

Unmapped custom attributes user

[image: Unmapped custom attributes user]

I would like to know why I'm not getting the mapped attributes from Cognito and why its not mapped to the user ( attributes like name, email, picture mapped and saved inside the user pool but resource protected attributes wont )